# One-way flight trip implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I came across the following problem (found on the SO link below):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991950/one-way-flight-trip-problem

> Given a flight trip that includes a number of transfers: we have a
>   ticket for each part of the trip; we do not stop twice in the same
>   airport; each ticket contains source and destination airport; all the
>   tickets we have are randomly sorted, and we forgot the original
>   departure airport and the last destination. We want to design an
>   algorithm to reconstruct the trip with minimum big-O complexity.

I tried to solve the problem in python in O(n) time complexity. Here is my solution:

```
L = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'G'), ('G', 'H'), ('H', 'I')]
# Note: the input L should normally be shuffled.

def getDepartureArrival(L):
    sources, destinations = zip(*L)
    sources = set(sources)
    destinations = set(destinations)

    for s in sources:
        if s not in destinations:
            depart = s
            break
    for d in destinations:
        if d not in sources:
            arriv = d
            break
    return depart, arriv
#

def getTrip(H):
    trip = [depart]
    k = depart
    while k != arriv:
        k = H[k]
        trip.append(k)
    return trip
#

depart, arriv = getDepartureArrival(L)
H = {s:d for (s,d) in L}
print getTrip(H)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have a clearer and more compact Python code than the one I wrote with more than 4 consecutive loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use global variables when not necessary. You can just directly pass `depart` and `arriv` to `getTrip`.

You should strive to have readable variable names. Just use `arrival` and `departure`.

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case_with_underscore` for variables and functions.

You can use `map` to cast both `sources` and `destinations` to `set`s directly. You can also use set subtraction to get the difference value only in one of them.

The `dict` constructor can directly take an iterable of pairs to build a dictionary.

You can make `get_trip` a generator, which simplifies the logic slightly.

I would add a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to allow importing stuff from this module without running the whole code.

```
import random


def get_departure_arrival(flights):
    """
    Find departure and arrival airport from chain of flights.

    Effectively the opposite of the itertools recipe pairwise:

    >>> get_departure_arrival([(s0, s1), (s1, s2), (s2, s3)])
    (s0, s3)

    Pairs do not have to be in order:

    >>> get_departure_arrival([(s0, s1), (s2, s3), (s1, s2)])
    (s0, s3)
    """
    sources, destinations = map(set, zip(*flights))

    depart = (sources - destinations).pop()
    arriv = (destinations - sources).pop()

    return depart, arriv


def get_trip(flights, depart, arriv):
    """
    Reconstruct a flight trip from pairs of departure and
    arrival airports and the first and last airport of the trip.
    """
    flight_dict = dict(flights)
    while depart != arriv:
        yield depart
        depart = flight_dict[depart]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flights = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'),
               ('E', 'F'), ('F', 'G'), ('G', 'H'), ('H', 'I')]
    random.shuffle(flights)

    depart, arriv = get_departure_arrival(flights)
    print list(get_trip(flights, depart, arriv))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any improvement that can be made algorithmically speaking (to optimize runtime) ?
A typo: the first arg in the definition of get_trip should be: flights.

Comment: @eLearner Well, I already changed the algorithm slightly using the set logic. But a performance improvement we would need a bigger test sample. As it stands now, both versions take about 0.01s on my machine...

Comment: @eLearner It is hard to make improvements without being able to profile the code to find bottlenecks, for which a realistic test sample is needed.

Comment: It would be nice if the revised code had docstrings.

Comment: @GarethRees There you go, docstrings just for you ;-)

Comment: @Graipher: Hopefully not just for me.

Comment: @GarethRees Well for you, for the OP, for posterity and, most importantly, for myself, so I get into the habit of including them every time :)